# Did the kid on the bus know that Peter is Spider-Man?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Towards the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War*, Peter Parker is on a school bus, presumably going to school [or on a field trip]. When Peter notices The Maw's ship in the distance, he immediately asks the kid in front of him to make a distraction. The kid pauses for a split second, then gets up and yells, "we're all gonna die!", and runs towards the back of the bus.

### Did he know that Peter Parker is Spider-Man?

Other than the comedy aspect of it, I find it odd that the kid didn't ask Peter why he needed to create a distraction, but, more importantly, it's curious that the kid chose "we're all going to die!" as a distraction instead of something else.

IMO, the kid reacted as if he actually thought they were going to die, specifically because Spider-Man was asking him to create the distraction. But, AFAIK, Peter Parker has kept his Spider-Man identity a secret.

So, was this kid really just causing a distraction, or, did he really think they were all going to die (or were in serious danger)?

Comment: It looked like he saw Ebony Maw's ship from the bus, so "we're all going to die" is both a convenient distraction and a legitimate fear

Comment: Yeah, I totally read the 'we're all going to die' is a cry of genuine fear from when he turns around and sees the ship hovering over Manhattan .... for all we know since he was wearing headphones he may not even have heard what Peter asks him to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That kid is Ned ( Peter's best friend) and he does know his secret identity, he discovered it in Spider-Man: Homecoming. Here is a clip of that scene:

Comment: Hah, wow.. literally the only MCU film I've yet to watch.

Comment: @Charles then you got a spoiler from that film :D

Comment: Lol, indeed I did. No worries though! I'm a pretty lax fan.